# Chose color in a \fill tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

Simply, I am drawing a dot in a 3D `tikzpicture` using

```
\fill (x,y,z) circle [radius=3pt, <somecoloroption>]
```

How can I change its color? None of `fill=red`,`draw=red`, just `red` changed the color, they are always black.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Ti*k*Z, the main command for paths is `\path`. However, we usually use `\draw`, which is `\path[draw]`, and `\fill`, which is `\path[fill]`. Therefore, if you want to customize the path, you have to put the option to the `\path` command "through" the `\draw`/`\fill` command:

```
\fill[red] (x,y,z) circle [radius=3pt];
% which is
% \path[fill=red] (x,y,z) circle [radius=3pt];
```